# Apache 2 not rewrite https traffic

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https

Apache 2.3 don't rewrite the https traffic,
this is my htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.it$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.it$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.org$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.org%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

and this is mi example.conf in site-aviable

```
    AccessFileName .htaccess
    <Directory /www/example.org/>
      Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

But not work for httpS!!
Only http traffic is rewrite

I want if you write https:// or http:// or without http(s) everything is redirected on https://www.example.org
How to do?

Best regards

Comment: Could you please place a dummy line like `------` in your htaccess file and then hit any url, if you are seeing 500 internal error then it means your htaccess is enabled else its not, please perform this test and let us know then.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I entered -------------- and it returned 500 error

Comment: What is your Apache version?

Comment: apache 2.3 thank you

Comment: Not sure the (implicit) AND and OR work as you intended to here to begin with. And the whole thing would probably be a lot easier, if you used _one_ condition, that checks that the host name is _not_ exactly `www.example.org`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you mean that instead of OR I should use for example NC? I'm going to try...

I have tried and nothing changes with NC instead of OR

Comment: Keep your HTTPS condition, and combine that with `[OR]` with `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.org$`, remove all the rest of the conditions. That should cover all cases.

Comment: @CBroe
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.org$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.org%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

now it is but it does not rewrite the url if instead I put http://www.example.com without HTTPS it works.
Best regards